# Socket.io installation on Win 7 fails

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I've installed NodeJs and tried to install Socket.io

Socket.io installation fails consecutively. I've tried several differend NodeJS versions (0.6.15,0.6.16,**0.6.17**,0.7.8). All fail to install socket.io.

The full log can be found on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/rkpAtYMT).

Console log is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs>npm install socket.io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.6
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.6.7
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.6
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.6.7
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.2.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ws
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.2.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ws
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/options
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/-/zeparser-0.0.5.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/options

> ws@0.4.14 install C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\socket.io\node_mo
dules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws
> node install.js

'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/-/zeparser-0.0.5.tgz

npm ERR! ws@0.4.14 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! `cmd "/c" "node install.js"` failed with 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ws@0.4.14 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the ws package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ws
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program File
s (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "socket.io"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs
npm ERR! node -v v0.7.8
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.18
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! message ws@0.4.14 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! message `cmd "/c" "node install.js"` failed with 1
npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

**Is there a workaround? How can I install Socket.IO on Windows 7 x64?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved on Node.js v0.8.3

Answer (score 0):

(Works for me with `0.6.15`, win7 x64)

I'm not sure how you installed node, but it seems like you don't have it in your path.
Try editing your PATH variable and add `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\`

Also, why are you installing in `Program Files`. This should be installed in your project folder. If you want to install a package globally you should use `npm -g`, but `socket.io` is not meant to be installed globally.

Comment: I've just used the MSI to install node. And it automatically installed it in "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"
I use the following command (in cmd) to install socket.io:
_C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs>npm install socket.io_

Comment: yes. I can execute other nodejs code. But can't install socket.io